# Does the shape of an acoustic/vocal booth matter for maximum isolation?

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, acoustics

I am building a vocal booth at home, so I can do voice over work. Now I have some Wood lying around, & will build the booth with wood.

I am confused as to, what shape I should build it in?  So, as to get the best sound (a full sound, rather than a box like tone)

proper square like this:

[image]

Or

Sides at an angle  - like this:

[image]

I have a busy road near my house, so I need to have maximum isolation . If there is anything else I need to keep in mind please let me know (

Comment: The interior shape is more about how the sound bounces inside. The difference between interior and exterior shape (and what goes in between) determines more about noise cancellation. I'm not enough of an acoustics guy to give you exact ideals though.

Answer (score 2):

More important is the isolation. I highly recommend using 3“ (or thicker) stone wool insulation completely covering the ceiling and walls on the inside. Cover it up with cloth so it's pretty, do not cover it with wood.
'Boxiness' comes from room modes which cause peaks and nulls at frequencies related to the distances between the surfaces. With proper absorption you will minimize the room modes at least in middle and upper frequencies.
Do not build a square. In fact try to avoid measurements which have the same divisible units. Ie instead of an 8 ft high 4 ft wide 6 ft long make it 8 ft 2 in, 4 ft, by 5.5 ft. Making surfaces not parallel is a great thing in reducing room modes, trapezoid>square. Irregular quadrilateral> Trapezoid.

Comment: Sorry I didn't look at your pics first. You're not building an iso booth just a baffle. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I also have some 1 inch mattress foam at at my place, which I was planning to put inside for insulation/absorption. Together with the wood(about 2 inch in thickness) Is that fine for sound absorption ? will it do the job?